# Standard info for hardware / performance questions

Tags: discussion

I think there should be minimum amount of info which users are asked to provide for questions about hardware problems or performance: Processor, RAM, graphic card (and which driver is being used), are they using a SSD or HDD, kernel version.

This might not really be enforcable (and shouldn't be: If the problem can be resolved without asking for this info, why care...), but having a canonical answer on how to collect this info would be a good place to direct users to which fail to provide necessary information.

Comment: I was under the impression that most of those questions will be closed as "too specific / opinion based".

Comment: [This says otherwise.](http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/117/68)

Comment: "AskUbuntu has a canonical question describing how to best conduct your own research outside of StackExchange." We need a reference question with a guide on how to identify your hardware and what to post for what issue.

Comment: @LewisGoddard can you give a link to the AskUbuntu question? There seems to be a lot of hardware specific questions that are unanswered

Comment: Lots of "will this thing work" get marked as a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/49412/support-for-hardware-components, and lots of "will my pc run it" are linked to http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

There are currently a couple of "canonical" hardware related posts. Please comment with any others that we could use to de-duplicate:

Minimum Requirements: [What are the minimum hardware requirements to run elementary OS?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/what-are-the-minimum-hardware-requirements-to-run-elementary-os)

Performance issues with Intel graphics: [How do I install the latest Intel Linux Graphics?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/how-do-i-install-the-latest-intel-linux-graphics)